# Python how to sum duplicates in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list

```
['OE21-k', 'OE28-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE-31-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE28-k']
```

And i want to know, how many OE21-k and how many OE28-k have.
Is there any way to sum and calc how many duplicates are there?

Comment: Counter - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: What do you mean by "sum" them? Do you mean simply counting the duplicates?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the occurrences just use the `count()` method.

```
['OE21-k', 'OE28-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE-31-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE28-k'].count('OE21-k')
```

e.g.

```
occurences = {}
l = ['OE21-k', 'OE28-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE-31-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE28-k'] 
for item in l:
    if item not in occurences.keys():
        occurences[item] = l.count(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `collections.Counter` is easy to use:

```py
from collections import Counter

items = ['OE21-k', 'OE28-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE-31-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE28-k']
c = Counter(items)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'OE21-k': 4, 'OE28-k': 2, 'OE-31-k': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
occurences = {}

l = ['OE21-k', 'OE28-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE-31-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE21-k', 'OE28-k']

for item in l:
    if item in occurences:
        occurences[item] += 1
    else:
        occurences[item] = 1
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.